# How hazelcast get overlay network ip in Docker Swarm

Tags: overlay, hazelcast, docker-swarm

in my 3 nodes Docker Swarm environment,with spring cloud jhispter,use hazelcast I can get my docker_gwbridge,but I wanna get my cluster overlay  ip address.

At setup with an warning "Could not find a matching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback addresses." then get the docker_gwbridge ip addresss, the address is not match with jhispter microservice ip address.

Comment: I am facing same issue, have you managed to figure out yet?

Comment: yes,  the solution is in https://github.com/bitsofinfo/hazelcast-docker-swarm-discovery-spi

Answer (score 0):

have find the solution, https://github.com/bitsofinfo/hazelcast-docker-swarm-discovery-spi,
with the two ways to solve network errors.